# Update query is not working in the function created but that same query when runs manually working

Tags: postgresql

I am creating function in which update command is used consecutively two times the first update is working and the second one is not

Have tried execute format () for the second update not working

While running the function the updation2 is not working but when I manually run this updation command the table get updated...

The code is as follows:

```
update edmonton.weekly_pmt_report 
  set permit_number = pmt.prnum 
  from(select permit_details,
        split_part(permit_details,'-',1) as prnum
       from edmonton.weekly_pmt_report) as pmt 
  where edmonton.weekly_pmt_report.permit_details = 
    pmt.permit_details;

execute format('update edmonton.weekly_pmt_report
  set address = ds_dt.adr,
      job_description = ds_dt.job,
      applicant = ds_dt.apnt
  from(select split_part(per_num,''-'',1) as job_id, 
        job_des as job,addr as adr, applic as apnt
        from edmonton.descriptive_details ) as ds_dt
  where edmonton.weekly_pmt_report.permit_number = 
    ds_dt.job_id');
```

Comment: You can edit the question,and add the code there.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: I created a function by incorporating this query, the first update has been done the table but the second update is not updating anything on the table

Comment: When I go to that function and manually run the second update query, query updates the table.

Comment: Is my execute format query is correct??

Answer (score 0):

That the second update query has value only 400 out of 1000 so the null columns are on the Top, that's why It seemed to be not working...